# Memory leak because of MapBox in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, mapbox

I use the MapBox SDK in my Unity project and I just display the map. I don't use other services like directions or so. Somehow I always get a error that there is a memory leak. Since my project is an Ios and Android app a memory leak doesn't sound that great to me haha.

The error with references is this:

```
A Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak. Allocated from:
Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1:.ctor(Byte[], Allocator)
UnityEngine.Networking.UploadHandlerRaw:.ctor(Byte[])
Mapbox.Unity.Telemetry.<PostWWW>d__8:MoveNext() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Telemetry\TelemetryEditor.cs:82)
Mapbox.Unity.Utilities.Routine:MoveNext() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Utilities\Runnable.cs:130)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2(IEnumerator)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
Mapbox.Unity.Utilities.Routine:.ctor(IEnumerator) (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Utilities\Runnable.cs:116)
Mapbox.Unity.Utilities.Runnable:Run(IEnumerator) (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Utilities\Runnable.cs:47)
Mapbox.Unity.Telemetry.TelemetryEditor:SendTurnstile() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Telemetry\TelemetryEditor.cs:37)
Mapbox.Unity.MapboxAccess:ConfigureTelemetry() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\MapboxAccess.cs:196)
Mapbox.Unity.MapboxAccess:SetConfiguration(MapboxConfiguration, Boolean) (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\MapboxAccess.cs:108)
Mapbox.Unity.MapboxAccess:LoadAccessToken() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\MapboxAccess.cs:161)
Mapbox.Unity.MapboxAccess:.ctor() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\MapboxAccess.cs:66)
Mapbox.Unity.MapboxAccess:get_Instance() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\MapboxAccess.cs:41)
Mapbox.Unity.Map.<SetupAccess>d__88:MoveNext() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Map\AbstractMap.cs:609)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged(String, Object)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String, Object)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(String)
Mapbox.Unity.Map.AbstractMap:MapOnStartRoutine(Boolean) (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Map\AbstractMap.cs:534)
Mapbox.Unity.Map.AbstractMap:Start() (at Assets\Mapbox\Unity\Map\AbstractMap.cs:500)
```

It points to MapBox scripts that come with the SDK. I don't know if I should include those here since I did not touch them in any way and they are very generic and point to a lot of other scripts.

Does anyone have any idea? Or can I maybe just ignore this and will my app work just fine? So far I have no issues testing for as far as I can tell.

Thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: The text indicates that `Mapbox.Unity.Map.AbstractMap` uses some unmanaged resources. Ubiquotus with any kind of high performance drawing or images. Unmanaged resource must be freed up using a call to Dispose. | Please show us how you create the instance and where - if at all - you dipose of it. My usual advise is: "Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a using block." But this might be the rare case where that is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following error will occur only in editor and will not affect the targeting platforms because there is **UNITY_EDITOR** macro present in your `Assets/Mapbox/Unity/Telemetry/TelemetryEditor.cs` script.

If you would still like to fix this error you must call Dispose once you have finished using a UnityWebRequest object, regardless of whether the request succeeded or failed, just replace the **PostWWW** method with the following:

```
        IEnumerator PostWWW(string url, string bodyJsonString)
        {
            byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);

#if UNITY_2017_1_OR_NEWER
            using (UnityWebRequest postRequest = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST"))
            {
                postRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                postRequest.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
                postRequest.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);

                yield return postRequest.SendWebRequest();

                while (!postRequest.isDone) { yield return null; }

                if (!postRequest.isNetworkError)
                {
#else
                var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.Add("user-agent", GetUserAgent());
                var www = new WWW(url, bodyRaw, headers);
                yield return www;

                while (!www.isDone) { yield return null; }

                // www doesn't expose HTTP status code, relay on 'error' property
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
                {
#endif
                    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Constants.Path.TELEMETRY_TURNSTILE_LAST_TICKS_EDITOR_KEY, "0");
                }
                else
                {
                    PlayerPrefs.SetString(Constants.Path.TELEMETRY_TURNSTILE_LAST_TICKS_EDITOR_KEY, DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! So do I get it right if I say this error will not cause issues with the Android and Ios builds? :)

Comment: @RicardoFrederiks You’re welcome. Yes you’re correct.

Answer (score 1):

The text indicates that Mapbox.Unity.Map.AbstractMap uses some unmanaged resources. This is ubiquitous with any class dealing with images or drawing. I personally do not know this class, but with that name it is not surprising at all.

Unmanaged resource are not automatically cleaned up by the GC in a timely manner. While there is usually a finalizer to clean up that resource *eventually*, it is usually no a option to wait. And in this case it seems there is even a exception to make sure you do not forget - incerdibly convenient!

It is your job to make sure the unmanaged resources are cleaned up before you drop the last reference, by calling `Mapbox.Unity.Map.AbstractMap.Dispose()`.

My general advise whenever you deal with anything disposeable is: "Create. use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, and ideally using the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)." It is usually adviseable to redesign your code so you can follow that pattern whenever remotely possible.

There is a very rare exception. In that rare case, you have to implement the [Dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

The Dispose pattern has two use cases:

- You handle unmanaged resources directly. This basically never happens. All the likely case are already covered by class libraries. In this case you write a Finalizer first, then add a Dispose function for convenience
- You have a field of any type that implements IDisposeable. In that case your own class must implement IDisposeable. The sole purpose is to relay the Dispose() call to whatever Disposeable fields your type contains. This is the 99% use case.

As the code is mostly indentical, usually the finalizer is part of the Dispose(bool) function. The only difference between fianlizer and Dispose are:

- Finalizer calls are *never* relayed to the Disposeable fields. The Finalizer is a mater between each Instance and the GC.
- A Dispose call is *always* relayed to Disposeable fields. That relay is literally the only reason you implement IDisposeable in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The thing here is that I did not write any scripts in Unity to get MapBox working. It's all drag and drop after adding the SDK by importing the UnityPackage. It is all generic, hard to understand (for me) scripts that do the work. So that's why it's weird for me that I have to dispose something. If I needed to write the scripts on my own and call upon a library then I understand I need to do it manually within the code. The answer after this one makes me believe the issue does not need to be solved because it only occurs in the Editor. :)

Comment: @RicardoFrederiks To me it sounds like there is a issue. You get the Warning only in the Editor. And you are going to ignore the issue.